# Visual Studio 2015 Analyzer with Code Fix does not support Roslyn 1.3.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, visual-studio-2017

I'm building an analyzer, Diagnostic + Code Fix with Roslyn. I created the Project using the given template, and I selected .NET Framework 4.6. I substituted the vsix PCL dependency with a standard Class Library Project (I will need to do some IO), used the same code and it ran as expected. I then proceeded to update Roslyn modules through the NuGet package manager to version 1.3.2 (which I need because I have written a .dll using version 1.3.2) and Initialize override just doesn't get called anymore.

```
        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        // TODO: Consider registering other actions that act on syntax instead of or in addition to symbols
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Analyzer%20Actions%20Semantics.md for more information
        context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.NamedType);
    }
```

I have done the same process with VS2017, and it worked immediately. What do I need to do for it to work with VS2015?

(Using enterprise edition with both.)

Comment: By default, the templates reference version 1.0.1 of the roslyn assemblies.  These assembly versions will work on any build of VS 2015 or VS 2017.  Once you referenced version 1.3.2 you analyzer became runnable only on VS 2015 Update 3 and higher.  Anyone with VS 2015 RTM, VS 2015 Update 1, or VS 2015 Update 2 will not be able to use your analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jonathon. I am running VS2015 Update 3, and the rest of the people in the company too. There'll be a change to VS2017 but not right now. Any idea of why it isn't running though it's VS2015 Update 3?

Comment: How are you installing this analyzer? are you using the nuget package, the vsix, or adding it via the reference manage?

Comment: For now, I'm just launching it through debug in visual studio which brings another instance of it. Is it no supposed to do so?

Comment: @JonathonMarolf What is the latest version of Roslyn I can reference and still support VS2015? Generally, does referencing Roslyn 1.x.y limit support to VS2015 Update x and above?

Comment: Yes, if you reference Roslyn 1.3.0 then only Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and newer compilers can load your analyzer.